# Add custom header to all responses from Traefik on Azure's Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, traefik

I've deployed Traefik on an Azure Service Fabric Cluster. Everything works fine as in Traefik (using SFC's APIs) find other guest services and dynamically create the frontend and backend profiles. So I'm not statically configuring any frontend.

Is there a way to tell Traefik to add a custom header to all responses coming from all the froentends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Traefik* has a custom header feature for matched frontend rules as described [here](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/servicefabric/#custom-headers).

The custom headers are applied per rule...

> Custom headers can be configured through the frontends, to add headers to either requests or responses **that match the frontend's rules**

Because you are using dynamic configuration, you will need to add these rules to the services, instead of setting in the traeffik configuration.

Something like:

```
<StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="WebServiceType">
  <Extensions>
      <Extension Name="Traefik">
        <Labels xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/03/fabact-no-schema">
          <Label Key="traefik.frontend.rule.example2">PathPrefixStrip: /a/path/to/strip</Label>
          <Label Key="traefik.enable">true</Label>
          <Label Key="traefik.frontend.headers.customRequestHeaders">heaver:value</Label>
        </Labels>
      </Extension>
  </Extensions>
</StatelessServiceType>
```

AFAIK, there is no way to apply to all responses in a global way.

Comment: I don't think this is answering my question. The "StatelessServiceType", as far as I understand, is defined in a Service Manifest files. As I mentioned, I don't have service manifest for guest services in SFC. Traefik discovers them by using SFC's APIs.

Comment: This was just an example, you would set the labels via SF API instead of the manifest, the working logic is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested XML in the accepted answer isn't gonna work for dynamically discovered services on SFC. I did accept it however since it pointed that it can be done through APIs.

For the benefit of others, to call the APIs, one could either use "sfctl" (Service Fabric's CLI) or directly call the API with cUrl.

I couldn't get the CLI to work (https://github.com/Microsoft/service-fabric-cli/issues/175), but I succeeded with cUrl:

```
curl -kv -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"PropertyName": "traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders","Value": {"Kind": "String","Data": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://some_value"}}' --cert /Users/me/client_cert.crt --key /Users/me/client_cert.key https://****.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Names/full/service/name/$/GetProperty?api-version=6.0 --http1.1
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-api-putproperty